# How to delete row when iterating into pandas Dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

This is my csv file:

```
A  B  C  D  J
0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  7  0  7
```

I need each time to select two columns and I verify this condition if I have Two 0 I delete the row so for exemple I select A and B

```
Input

A  B  
0  1  
0  0  
1  1  
0  0  
0  0  

Output 
A  B  
0  1  
1  1
```

And Then I select A and C ..

I used This code for A and B but it return errors

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')

a=df['A']
b=df['B']

indexes_to_drop = []

for i in df.index:
   if df[(a==0) & (b==0)] :
   indexes_to_drop.append(i)

df.drop(df.index[indexes_to_drop], inplace=True )
```

Any help please!

Comment: is the check just for specific 2 columns?

Comment: yes each time for just two columns

Comment: so you need to check every combinations of columns? can you explain the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we make your desired combinations of column A with all the rest, then we use `iloc` to select the correct rows per column combination:

```
idx_ranges = [[0,i] for i in range(1, len(df.columns))]
dfs = [df[df.iloc[:, idx].ne(0).any(axis=1)].iloc[:, idx] for idx in idx_ranges]
```

```
print(dfs[0], '\n')
print(dfs[1], '\n')
print(dfs[2], '\n')
print(dfs[3])

   A  B
0  0  1
2  1  1 

   A  C
2  1  1
4  0  7 

   A  D
2  1  0 

   A  J
2  1  0
4  0  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not iterate. Create a Boolean Series to slice your DataFrame:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']

m = df[cols].ne(0).any(1)
df.loc[m]

   A  B  C  D  J
0  0  1  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  0  0
```

---

You can get all combinations and store them in a `dict` with `itertools.combinations`. Use `.loc` to select both the rows and columns you care about.

```
from itertools import combinations

d = {c: df.loc[df[list(c)].ne(0).any(1), list(c)]
     for c in list(combinations(df.columns, 2))}

d[('A', 'B')]
#   A  B
#0  0  1
#2  1  1

d[('C', 'J')]
#   C  J
#2  1  0
#4  7  7
```

Comment: @OumaymaHamdi I see, I've added a solution for all two-pair combinations.